# Problem encountered when try to convert a xml file to tibble dateframe

Tags: r, xml, tidyverse, tibble

I have a problem while trying to convert a xml file to a tidy tabular format (tibble in this case), however, after the as_tibble() function, R returns error as it asking for naming the columns in the previous df (which is not a dataframe at the input stage).

```r
pacman::p_load(pacman, tidyverse, XML2R)

df <- "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml" %>%
  XML2Obs() %>%
  collapse_obs() %>%
  print()

# See variable (node) names and IDs
df %>%
  names() %>%
  print()
#>  [1] "MRData"                                                                
#>  [2] "MRData//RaceTable"                                                     
#>  [3] "MRData//RaceTable//Race"                                               
#>  [4] "MRData//RaceTable//Race//Circuit"                                      
#>  [5] "MRData//RaceTable//Race//Circuit//CircuitName"                         
#>  [6] "MRData//RaceTable//Race//Circuit//Location"                            
#>  [7] "MRData//RaceTable//Race//Circuit//Location//Country"                   
#>  [8] "MRData//RaceTable//Race//Circuit//Location//Locality"                  
#>  [9] "MRData//RaceTable//Race//Date"                                         
#> [10] "MRData//RaceTable//Race//RaceName"                                     
#> [11] "MRData//RaceTable//Race//ResultsList//Result"                          
#> [12] "MRData//RaceTable//Race//ResultsList//Result//Constructor"             
#> [13] "MRData//RaceTable//Race//ResultsList//Result//Constructor//Name"       
#> [14] "MRData//RaceTable//Race//ResultsList//Result//Constructor//Nationality"
#> [15] "MRData//RaceTable//Race//ResultsList//Result//Driver"                  
#> [16] "MRData//RaceTable//Race//ResultsList//Result//Driver//DateOfBirth"     
#> [17] "MRData//RaceTable//Race//ResultsList//Result//Driver//FamilyName"      
#> [18] "MRData//RaceTable//Race//ResultsList//Result//Driver//GivenName"       
#> [19] "MRData//RaceTable//Race//ResultsList//Result//Driver//Nationality"     
#> [20] "MRData//RaceTable//Race//ResultsList//Result//Grid"                    
#> [21] "MRData//RaceTable//Race//ResultsList//Result//Laps"                    
#> [22] "MRData//RaceTable//Race//ResultsList//Result//Status"                  
#> [23] "MRData//RaceTable//Race//ResultsList//Result//Time"


# Extract data and save as tibble
df %<>%  # %<>% is the compound assignment pipe operator
  as.list()%>%
  as_tibble() %>%                        # Save as tibble
  select(                                # Select data
    Race = matches("RaceName"),          # Get race name
    FirstName = matches("GivenName"),    # Get first name
    LastName = matches("FamilyName"),    # Get last name
    Team = matches("Constructor//Name")  # Get team name
  ) %>% 
  print()  # Each column is a list with two values (oops)
#> Error: Columns 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 18 more must be named.
#> Use .name_repair to specify repair.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

```r
dput(head(df))
#> structure(list(MRData = structure(c("f1", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", 
#> "30", "0", "9"), .Dim = c(1L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("series", 
#> "url", "limit", "offset", "total"))), `MRData//RaceTable` = structure(c("1954", 
#> "1", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml"), .Dim = c(1L, 
#> 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("season", "position", "url"))), 
#>     `MRData//RaceTable//Race` = structure(c("1954", "1954", "1954", 
#>     "1954", "1954", "1954", "1954", "1954", "1954", "1", "2", 
#>     "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", 
#>     "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", 
#>     "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", 
#>     "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", 
#>     "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml"
#>     ), .Dim = c(9L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("season", "round", 
#>     "url"))), `MRData//RaceTable//Race//Circuit` = structure(c("galvez", 
#>     "indianapolis", "spa", "reims", "silverstone", "nurburgring", 
#>     "bremgarten", "monza", "pedralbes", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", 
#>     "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", 
#>     "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", 
#>     "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", 
#>     "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml"
#>     ), .Dim = c(9L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("circuitId", 
#>     "url"))), `MRData//RaceTable//Race//Circuit//CircuitName` = structure(c("Autódromo Juan y Oscar Gálvez", 
#>     "Indianapolis Motor Speedway", "Circuit de Spa-Francorchamps", 
#>     "Reims-Gueux", "Silverstone Circuit", "Nürburgring", "Circuit Bremgarten", 
#>     "Autodromo Nazionale di Monza", "Circuit de Pedralbes", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", 
#>     "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", 
#>     "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", 
#>     "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", 
#>     "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml"
#>     ), .Dim = c(9L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("XML_value", 
#>     "url"))), `MRData//RaceTable//Race//Circuit//Location` = structure(c("-34.6943", 
#>     "39.795", "50.4372", "49.2542", "52.0786", "50.3356", "46.9589", 
#>     "45.6156", "41.3903", "-58.4593", "-86.2347", "5.97139", 
#>     "3.93083", "-1.01694", "6.9475", "7.40194", "9.28111", "2.11667", 
#>     "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", 
#>     "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", 
#>     "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", 
#>     "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml", 
#>     "http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml"), .Dim = c(9L, 
#>     3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("lat", "long", "url")))), .Dim = 6L, .Dimnames = list(
#>     c("MRData", "MRData//RaceTable", "MRData//RaceTable//Race", 
#>     "MRData//RaceTable//Race//Circuit", "MRData//RaceTable//Race//Circuit//CircuitName", 
#>     "MRData//RaceTable//Race//Circuit//Location")))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Without see what the original df looks like anything would just be a just. Can you rerun the first line again.  Then run `dput(head(df))` and then edit your question adding the output.

Comment: hello, the df object is actually data.frame on the input  stage for as_tibble, it is more like a list (sorry I am not very familiar with it ). I added the outcome of dput(head(df)) after the as-tibble error as shown above. @Dave2e

Comment: The data you provide is all ready a list of data frames/tibbles.  So I don't understand the purpose of: `%>%  as.list()%>% as_tibble()`.  Most likely you need to combines those tables together and then filter. You will need to clarify what is the indented end result.

Answer (score 0):

This is from a LinkedIn course on "data wrangling in R"  I am seeing the same error. I tried every standard way listed in Google. Nothing worked. Question is, did this procedure ever work, or has something changed in R between now and when the course was created.

Comment: This is probably better as a comment than as an answer.